# MVC send value string controller to view

Tags: php

controller

```
<?php
$value = $this->input->post('value');
$this->$data["value "] = $value;
$this->output(view,$this->data);
?>
```

error

> Message: Undefined variable: data

Comment: Don't use the `$` before `$data`; like `$this->data["value "] = $value;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide full error information, but I guess it's this line:

```
$this->$data["value "] = $value;
```

It probably should be

```
$this->data["value "] = $value; //no $ before data
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Jakub Matczak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1003915/jakub-matczak) propably fixes your problem - you could alternatively just directly send the `POST` parameters object to the view.

```
/* 
* $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter 
* $this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter
*/
$this->output(view, $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$value = $this->input->post('value');
$data["newvalue"] = $value;
$this->output(view,$data);
?>
```

and you should call **$newvalue** in view.